# How to remove padding on left of logo in action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

My activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Mainfest file

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden">
    <intent-filter>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I tried out many things but nothings seems to work thats why i uploaded this question. I removed the padding and even tried contentInsets but nothing is working.

[image: I want to remove that yellow space]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigate);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black);

 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
}
```

drawer_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation_to_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_to_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_to_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: check my answer

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use content inset feature.
The left inset is caused by Toolbar's contentInsetStart which by default is 16dp.

Try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" />
```

And add this at your root.

```
xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto";
```

Try  this in your android code

```
Toolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(0);
```

In worst case try this.
add below code in your activity onCreate.

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
view.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: NO its not working and it should be xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"; which is already there.

Answer (score 0):

The Left inset is by default is `16dp` but you are adding icon that's why the Left inset is now `72dp`. you can change by adding below code to `Toolbar`.

```
 app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
 app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

**OR**

you can also set Padding Programatically below way

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
int padding = 50;
toolbar.setPadding(padding, toolbar.getPaddingTop(), padding, toolbar.getPaddingBottom());
```

**One More Important Note :**

> you can add not `Icon` and `Title` both at a time. As in documentation
>   mention you can add one thing `Either (Icon) or (Title)` at a time.

Comment: the screenshot i am showing is working fine when i am trying to add both at the same time. I already tried removing the padding and setting the contentInsetLeft and start which is not helping me either,